# Ruby Sinatra concurrency issue with dynamic lambda binding

Tags: ruby, multithreading, logging, concurrency

I have a Sinatra application where I pass a lambda to an external logger gem and provide it the context of the current request so it can extract out the session id.

The issue I have is that when I pass the context it is scoped to the first request. I've looked into dynamic binding with lambdas but as of yet have not found a way to get it to work within this particular scenario.

The line in the logger can be seen here: https://github.com/BBC-News/alephant-logger-json/blob/master/lib/alephant/logger/json.rb#L18

A pseudo version of our Sinatra code would like something like:

```
require "alephant/logger/json"
require "sinatra/base"

class App < Sinatra::Base
  set :sessions, true

  attr_reader :alj

  def initialize
    @alj    = Alephant::Logger::JSON
    @logger = alj.new "./app.log"
    super()
  end

  before do
    p "session id (outside lambda): #{session[:session_id]}" # <= correct value
    alj.session -> { p "session id (inside lambda): #{session[:session_id]}"; session[:session_id] } unless alj.session?
  end

  get "/" do
    @logger.info :foo => :bar
    "content"
  end
end
```

I originally put in the `unless alj.session?` conditional check because I assumed that the lambda would only need to be set once and that it would be able to reference its parents scope (which it does, but not *per request*).

Now I could remove the `unless alj.session?` part and then it would in theory work because I'd be resetting the lambda for each request.

But I don't believe this would work in a highly concurrent situation where the server was context switching between threads.

By that I mean, I foresee a scenario such as:

```
-> user 1 request (session id: 123)
-> context switch
-> user 2 request (session id: 456)
-> context switch
-> user 1 assigns lambda to the logger (has scope/ref: 123)
-> user 1 routing goes off and gets content
-> context switch
-> user 2 assigns lambda to the logger (has scope/ref: 456)
-> context switch
-> user 1 calls 'log.info' and now user 1 (123) is recorded with id 456
```

I have the freedom to change the code in the logger but I don't really want to change its API (e.g. I don't want to have to say `logger.info(session_id, ...orginal args...)` because that means it's now coupled to an id needing to be provided (I'd also have to provide the session id at every log call which would be very tedious).

I'd prefer the logger to lookup that information and then no-op if it wasn't available.

I've tried using dynamic binding, eval, yielding to blocks. Without any success.

Don't know if there is a solution to this problem. Would be great to get feedback and ideas/examples.

Thanks